# On Paypal website, I don't want to show SKU information

Tags: paypal

When a customer process order with paypal, on paypal checkout page, all products SKU info are showing

How can I make the SKU info does not show on paypal site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are happy just showing a summary of the cart you can change a setting in the back-end under System > Configuration > Paypal 
switch Transfer Line Items to No

[image]